# Assign code blocks to a property objective c

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, codeblocks, uiapplication

I'm attempting to get Background App Refresh going in my iOS application. However, I'm having some trouble understanding code blocks.

I've done some research on it, and would say I have a beginner's understanding so far. The method in question is:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
```

This method wants a UIBackgroundFetchResult return type. Due to the complexity of my application though, I cannot return that with ease. There's a lot that happens when pulling data from the internet in Background mode.

In the body of that method, I have a custom method that also has a completion block. What I'm trying to do is define another custom method in my code that would be assigned to the completion handler.

In my data manager, I have a property defined as :

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^fetchCompleted)(UIBackgroundFetchResult);
```

In the performFetchWtihCompletionHandler method implementation, I call on my data manager:

```
-(void)fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    _fetchCompleted = completionHandler;

    _state = DMSMT_WaitingForPartnerData;
    [self getActiveQueues];
}
```

Once my downloads are completed, I call on the fetchCompleted method:

```
[self fetchCompleted];
```

Herein lies my problem. I need to pass a UIBackgroundFetchResult argument, but I see no way to do that. I tried [self fetchCompleted:UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData]; but it yells at me.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here was the fix. So simple!

```
if(_fetchCompleted != nil){
    [self fetchCompleted](UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating fetchCompleted as a method but it is a block! Try this out:

```
-(void)getActiveQueues {
    // Do some work here
    // When you are finished...

    // Set the appropriate result
    UIBackgroundFetchResult result;

    // Check to make sure fetchCompleted is not NULL
    if (self.fetchCompleted) {
        // Invoke the block!
        self.fetchCompleted(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. I hate it when it's such a simple syntax problem! ugh

Answer (score 1):

> This method wants a UIBackgroundFetchResult return type

No, it wants a `void` return type. One of the parameters is of type `UIBackgroundFetchResult`. Parameters are not return results. `UIBackgroundFetchResult` is just **a type of variable**.

Which appears to flow into your error. `[self fetchCompleted]` is the getter that will return the `fetchCompleted` variable. It doesn't do anything with it.

To perform a block, use function-like syntax. E.g. `[self fetchCompleted]()`.